# reduce font size but only when height decreases

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that comes out on click, and the design of the font is very large, so when the screen height is reduced some of the text gets hidden. Is there a way to decrease font size for only when the height is reduced? not the width? Using a media query for height kind of messes with the mobile font size.
Is there another method that I'm not thinking of the fix this issue?
First screenshot is of the nav when the height reduced, you can see the text becomes squashed.
[image]

[image]

This second image is how the nav looks at full height. I want it to keep this spacing

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query like this:

```
@media (max-height: 600px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

You can play with max and min properties, according to the sizes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using **`vh`** value for `font size`.

```
h1{
   fontsize: 10vh;
}
```